# Binary data different when viewed with CFDUMP

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have a SQL Server database that has a table that contains a field of type varbinary(256).

When I view this binary field via a query in MMS, the value looks like this:

> 0x004BC878B0CB9A4F86D0F52C9DEB689401000000D4D68D98C8975425264979CFB92D146582C38D74597B495F87FEA09B68A8440A

When I view this same field (and same record) using CFDUMP, the value looks like this:

> 075-56120-80-53-10279-122-48-1144-99-21104-1081000-44-42-115-104-56-10584373873121-49-714520101-126-61-115116891237395-121-2-96-101104-886810

(For the example below, the original binary value will be `@A`, and the CFDUMP value above will be `@B`)

I have tried using `CAST(@B as varbinary(256))` but didn't get the same value as `@A`.

What must I do to convert the value retrieved from CFDUMP into the correct binary representation?

Note: I no longer have the applicable records in the database.  I need to convert `@B` into the correct value that can re-INSERT into a varbinary(256) field.

Answer (score 3):

(Expanded from comments)

I do not mean this sarcastically, but what difference does it make how they *display* binary? It is simply a difference in how the data is presented. It does not mean the actual binary values differ.

It is similar to how dates are handled. Internally, they are a big numbers. But since most people do not know which date `1234567890` represents, applications chose to display the number in a more human friendly format. So SSMS might present the date as `2009-02-13 23:31:30.000`, while CF might present it as `{ts '2009-02-13 23:31:30'}`. Even though the presentations differ, it still the same value internally.

As far as binary goes, SSMS displays it as hexadecimal. If you use [`binaryEncode()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f65.html) on your query column, and convert the binary to hex, you can see it is the same value. Just without the leading `0x`:

```
  writeDump( binaryEncode(yourQuery.binaryColumn, "hex") )
```

If you are having some other issue with binary, could you please elaborate?

**Update:**

Unfortunately, I do not think you can easily convert the cfdump representation back into binary. Unlike Railo's implementation, Adobe's `cfdump` just concatenates the numeric representation of the individual bytes into one big string, with no delimiter. (The dashes are simply negative numbers). You can reproduce this by looping through the bytes of your sample string. The code below produces the same string of numbers you posted.

```
   bytes = binaryDecode("004BC878B0CB9A4F...", "hex");
   for (i=1; i<=arrayLen(bytes); i++) {
       WriteOutput( bytes[i] );
   }
```

I suppose it is theoretically possible to convert that string into binary, but it would be very difficult. AFAIK, there is no way to *accurately* determine where one number (or byte) begins and the other ends. There are some clues, but ultimately it would come down to guesswork.

Railo's implementation, displays the byte values separated by a dash "-". Two consecutive dashes indicates a negative number. ie "0", "75", "-56", ...

> 0-75--56-120--80--53--102-79--122--48--11-44--99--21-104--108-1-0-0-0--44--42--115--104--56--105-84-37-38-73-121--49--71-45-20-101--126--61--115-116-89-123-73-95--121--2--96--101-104--88-68-10

So you could probably parse that string back into an array of bytes. Then insert the binary into your database using `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BINARY" ..>`. Unfortunately that does not help you, but the explanation might help the next guy.

At this point, I think your best bet is to just restore the data from a database backup.

Comment: I accidentally deleted two records that I still have available via a CFDUMP, and I am trying to recover the binary fields, which are being displayed differently than they do in SSMS.  I will try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: So...my problem is that the data is NO LONGER in the database, so I need to convert the CFDUMP representation of this data to something I can re-INSERT as a varbinary(256) into the database.  Getting errors when I use BinaryEncode or BinaryDecode.

Comment: I have both.  I looked at the html source, and it didn't appear any different.

Comment: Ugh .. looking into it further, you may be out of luck. I think your best bet is to restore the data from a database backup. See my updated response.